# State in React component not setting data when the browser (tab) is refreshed

Tags: html, reactjs, frontend

I have this simple react component that gets data from an API (fetch called in `UseEffect`), and displays it using HTML. When I refresh the page, all html disappears from the page and it goes blank. What's peculiar is that when I instead make some changes in the code editor and let react autoupdate the page after saving, it displays everything just fine.

Here's the code snippet for the component:

```
export function AgentCard(props){
    console.log("agentcard function");
    const [agentData,setAgentData] = useState({});

    useEffect(()=> {
        console.log('running useEffect')
        axios.get('https://valorant-api.com/v1/agents/').then(res=>{
            var agentRes;

            for (const agent of res.data['data']){
                if (agent['displayName'] === props.agentName){ agentRes = agent}
            }

            setAgentData(agentRes);

            console.log(agentData)
        })
    },[])

    return(
        <div className='AgentCard'>
            <h2>{agentData['displayName']}</h2> 
            <img src={agentData['displayIcon']}></img>
            <div className='AgentCardBody'>
                <div className='AbilitiesBar'>
                   <img src={agentData['abilities'][0]['displayIcon']} className='AbilitiesIcon'></img>
                    <img src={agentData['abilities'][1]['displayIcon']} className='AbilitiesIcon'></img>
                    <img src={agentData['abilities'][2]['displayIcon']} className='AbilitiesIcon'></img>
                    <img src={agentData['abilities'][3]['displayIcon']} className='AbilitiesIcon'></img>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
```

After some digging and logging, what I found is that when I refresh the page, the state (`agentData`), is saved to this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkFCv.jpg

and get the following error in the console:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJUUj.jpg

But once I make any change to the editor and let react autorefresh, the logs show that the state `agentData` has the right data object pulled from the API.

Also, this only happens when I have the following part of the code running

```
<img src={agentData['abilities'][0]['displayIcon']} className='AbilitiesIcon'></img>
<img src={agentData['abilities'][1]['displayIcon']} className='AbilitiesIcon'></img>
<img src={agentData['abilities'][2]['displayIcon']} className='AbilitiesIcon'></img>
<img src={agentData['abilities'][3]['displayIcon']} className='AbilitiesIcon'></img>
```

Once I comment this out, everything displays correctly even after a browser refresh

I know the way I've posed the question is confusing, but I'm new to front end development and don't really know what I'm supposed to look for here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because `agentData.abilities` returns undefined (remember that you have an empty object that is asynchronously populated), but you're trying to access it in your template as if an array is present.

You can solve this easily if you conditionally render those `<img>` elements when `agentData.abilities` is not undefined, i.e.:

```
return(
    <div className='AgentCard'>
        <h2>{agentData['displayName']}</h2> 
        <img src={agentData['displayIcon']}></img>
        <div className='AgentCardBody'>
            {agentData.abilities && (
                <div className='AbilitiesBar'>
                    <img src={agentData.abilities[0].displayIcon} className='AbilitiesIcon' />
                    <img src={agentData.abilities[1].displayIcon} className='AbilitiesIcon' />
                    <img src={agentData.abilities[2].displayIcon} className='AbilitiesIcon' />
                    <img src={agentData.abilities[3].displayIcon} className='AbilitiesIcon' />
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

Even better: you can simply iterate through the first 4 entries in `agentData.abilities` to keep your DOM a bit simpler:

```
return(
    <div className='AgentCard'>
        <h2>{agentData['displayName']}</h2> 
        <img src={agentData['displayIcon']}></img>
        <div className='AgentCardBody'>
            <div className='AbilitiesBar'>
                {agentData.abilities && agentData.abilities.slice(0,4).forEach(ability => (
                    <img src={ability.displayIcon} className='AbilitiesIcon' />
                )}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

Comment: Yup this was the problem, I set initial state to null and rendered the images when state is not null